# Create Folders and Moving Files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've seen similar questions and used them as a basis for what i'm trying to do here.  I have a folder with many files that are named like "Author Name - Book Title.azw".

I'd like to create sub-folders for each author and move all their books into that folder.  This is the script i have so far.  It successfully creates folder for the Authors, but it chokes on the move-item, says Could not find a part of the path.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -file

foreach ($file in $files){

$title = $file.ToString().Split('-') 
$author = $title[0]
if (!(Test-Path $author))
{
    Write-Output "Creating Folder $author"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $author
}

Write-Output "Moving $file to $author" 
Move-Item -Path $file -Destination $author -Force
}
```

Comment: i see that you already have your solution - a full path for `-Destination` ... so this is just FYI. the `$File` variable in your code will hold a _fileinfo_ object, not a filename. the `.ToString()` will give you a stringified version of the default property - the `.Name`. that gives you want you want _in this case_ ... but it is a bad way to get there. [*grin*] take a look at the `.Basename` and `.Name` properties of a fileinfo object. the either of those are safer to use than hoping the default property is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```
Get-ChildItem -file | foreach {
  $title = $_.ToString().Split('-') 
  $author = $title[0]
  if (!(Test-Path $author))
  {
    Write-Host "Creating Folder $($author)"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$author"
   }

  Write-Host "Moving $($_) to $($author)" 
Move-Item -Path "$_" -Destination "$author" -Force
}
```

You must surround file paths in double quotes. So your code was not working.

Comment: I tried this and the same thing happens.  It errors out on Move Item : Could not find a part of the path.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to move files in a directory to sub folders where the author names are used as the sub folder names. You can try this solution to achieve this.

```
# Folder which contains files
$Path = "PATH_TO_FILES"

# Make sure path is a directory
if (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {

    # Go through each file in folder
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | ForEach-Object {

        # Get full path of file
        $filePath = $_.FullName

        # Extract author
        $author = $_.BaseName.Split("-")[0].Trim()

        # Create subfolder if it doesn't exist
        $subFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $author
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $subFolderPath -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $subFolderPath -ItemType Directory
        }

        # Move file to subfolder
        Move-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $subFolderPath
    }
}
```

Comment: This works best so far but it doesn't end up moving all the files.  But it gives no output as to what the problem is.  If i rerun it, it tells me the files are in use.